# Creating a new theme with Material-ui Version 5 with react version 18.01 - Error using '@mui/styles'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react V.18.01 and Material-ui v.5, and my application is giving me a error explained below, I would like a code review, once that I'm a beginner dev please.
I'm following this video to build my application.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIIJfmDnvPE&ab_channel=TheNetNinja
**Question: How to solve the issue of @mui/styles on import? What is happening here?**

ERROR in ./src/App.js 8:0-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/styles' in '/home/flavio/CashFlowBr/cashflowbr/src'

ERROR in ./src/pages/Banks.js 11:0-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/styles' in '/home/flavio/CashFlowBr/cashflowbr/src/pages'

I'm pasting my codes of the files, where should happens the changes.

```js
import Notes from './pages/Notes';
import Banks from './pages/Banks';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { styled } from '@mui/styles';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        type: 'ligth',
        main: '#fefefe',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#f50057',
      },

    },
    props: {
      MuiTooltip: {
        arrow: true,
      },
    },
      typography: {
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
        fontWeigthLigth: 400,
        fontWeigthRegular: 500,
        fontWeigthMedium: 600,
        fontWeigthBold: 700,
      }
 
})


class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
          <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Notes}/>
            <Route path="/bancos" component={ Banks }/>
          </Switch>
         </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
      )
    }
};

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { blue } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) ({
    field: {
        margimTop: 20,
        margimBottom: 20,
        display: "block",
    }
    
}));

export default function Bancos(){
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
    const [nameError, setNameError] = useState(false)
    const [addressError, setAddressError] = useState(false)

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setNameError(false)
        setAddressError(false)

        if(name == ''){
            setNameError(true)
        }

        if(address == ''){
            setAddressError(true)
        }

        if( name && address){
            console.log(name,address)
        }
    }

    return(
        <Container>
           <Typography  variant="h6" color="textSecondary" align="center" gutterBottom>
               Cadastrar um novo Banco
           </Typography>

            <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextField label="Nome do Banco" variant="outlined" color="secondary"
                fullWidth required className={classes.field} 
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} error={nameError}/>
                 <TextField label="Endereço" variant="outlined" color="secondary"
                fullWidth required className={classes.field} 
                onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)} error={addressError}/>

                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary"
                 endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRightIcon />} 
                >
                 Salvar
                </Button>
            </form>

           
        </Container>
    )
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```js
Console log error:

index.js:16 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@mui/styles'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:16:1)
    at Module../src/pages/Banks.js (index.js:16:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Module../src/App.js (interopRequireDefault.js:7:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (App.js:51:1)
webpackMissingModule @ index.js:16
./src/pages/Banks.js @ index.js:16
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/App.js @ interopRequireDefault.js:7
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/index.js @ App.js:51
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
localhost/:1 Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first reaction would be to make sure that I'd installed the dependencies correctly - try running either `yarn` or `npm i` (depending on your project) and check the output in the terminal doesn't show any errors.

**Update:**
I checked [the source repo](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/material-ui-tut) of the YouTube link you posted and it doesn't have `@mui` listed in the `package.json` originally. I haven't watched the video, but I would guess that there is a step to run something like `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` which you haven't done, so the module isn't installed and available yet.

Comment: Mr. James, thank you for your answer, I'll try your suggestion, but the video, the author was using another Material-ui version. Version 5 of Material -ui had some changes in the codes and functions, styles is one of those. Also some functions like ThemeProvider, do not work with react 18 on StrictMode, but the documentation, don't mention what to use instead. So I need an specialist in Material-ui to help with these errors. If your suggestion works I'll let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've made the installation and the both Errors persist. So, there is another way to use @mui/styles that I can't figure out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I solved the erros with npm install @mui/styles --force, follow  the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/styles . Thank you James. Best Regards.